# Fontawesome LaTeX Configuration

Tags: biblatex

All my references (bib file) has notes like:

```
note= "Available on: \href{https://someplace}{\textcolor{blue}{\faExternalLink}}. Accessed date: somedate."
```

Is there any command to 'turn off' or 'bypass'  '`\faExternalLink`' and show full `\href{path}` on pdf latex documents (bibliography)?

Comment: Please provide a final example (image for example) of what You want to achieve

Comment: If you are really using `biblatex` this should be fixed on the `.bib` file level. `biblatex` has dedicated fields for the URL and access date. `note= "Available on: \href{https://foo.edu}{\textcolor{blue}{\faExternalLink}}. Accessed date: 7 January 2023."` should be `url = {https://foo.edu}, urldate = {2023-01-07},`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder r<moewe>.
But considering the way the bib file is coded:

note= "Available on: \href{https://foo.edu}{\textcolor{blue}{\faExternalLink}}. Accessed date: 7 January 2023."

I'm getting the "\faExternalLink" symbol on my bibliography:

Available on <symbol>. Accessed date: jun. 2021.

What I was wondering is if there is a way the bypass Fontawesome and restore full path url (on bib.file), something like this:

Available on: http:www.someplace.com. Accessed date: jun. 2021.

Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 2):

This is really something that ought to be fixed on the `.bib` file level.

I'm assuming your are using `biblatex` as the tags suggest.

Then

```
note      = "Available on:
             \href{https://example.edu/~elk/bronto}{\textcolor{blue}{\faExternalLink}}.
             Accessed date: 7~January 2023.",
```

should be

```
url     = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto},
urldate = {2023-01-07},
```

But if you cannot change that, then the following pretty hacky workaround locally redefines `\href` to just print the URL. This definition will not be able to deal with all special characters that normally need escaping.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{note}{%
  \renewcommand*{\href}[2]{\url{##1}}%
  #1%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  note      = "Available on:
               \href{https://example.edu/~elk/bronto}{\textcolor{blue}{\faExternalLink}}.
               Accessed date: 7~January 2023.",
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, Anne (1972). A Theory on Brontosauruses. Available on: https://example.edu/~elk/bronto. Accessed date: 7 January 2023. London: Monthy & Co.]

Of course this also assumes that at least within `note` you never need the original definition of `\href`.

Comment: Thank you very much [moewe]!